How does the interpretation of 'δικαιωθήσονται' affect the way we understand Romans 2:13?
Text: Romans 2:13 (NET)

For it is not those who hear the law who are righteous before God, but those who do the law will be declared righteous.


It's an important question to say the least. Some people are content being a "pew warmer" or "passive participant" in their faith. That said, I feel like this question will invite too much opinion based answers so I'll leave a comment. Faith should be lived out in concrete actions and behaviors that align with God’s laws. This is not about earning salvation through works, but about demonstrating the authenticity of one’s faith through action. To actually use the principles of our faith in our daily lives, to be ‘doers’ and not just ‘hearers’.

Is not Matt 5:17-19 and Eph 2:10 the answer to this question?

Paul puts it all together in the first eight chapters of Romans.

Pauls argument is nobody obeys the law  and declared righteous by it, except Jesus of course, who obtained a righteousness thereby to give to others who have no righteousness of their own. The context matters.

The title question is now modified for more objective discussion.

The Greek in question, dikaiothesontai, is translated "shall be justified". That phrase comes after "...the doers of the law". Please bear with me as I take the whole verse, and the context it is set in, to see how it is to affect the way in which one lives out their faith.
The Apostle Paul was concerned to write about the vast subject of how every person, believer in God or unbeliever, legalistic law-keeper or 'minimalistic' law-keeper, did not have a leg to stand on when it comes to justifying themselves before God. Consider Paul's opening verse in that chapter:

"Therefore thou art inexcusable, O man, whosoever thou art that
judgest: for wherein thou judgest another, thou condemnest thyself;
for thou that judgest does the same things. But we are sure that the
judgment of God is according to truth against them which commit such
things." Romans 2:1-2 A.V.

Context gives the interpretation, which might be summed up as, "Nobody can keep the perfect law of God, breaking of which brings judgment from God. Those who like to think they can, and do, keep the law of God, shall never be justified before God on that basis, for they will discover on the Day of Judgment that they failed to keep it. Worse still, if they judged others as law-breakers, hypocrisy will be added to the charges against them."
As Paul said further on:

"Thou that makest thy boast of the law, through breaking the law
dishonourest thou God... Therefore by the deeds of the law there shall
no flesh be justified in his sight: for by the law is the knowledge of
sin."

As it takes eight whole chapters for Paul to work out, and unfold, this matter of dikaiothesontai (shall be justified), the only way to answer this question is to go through all eight chapters with due diligence, not ever taking a verse here and a verse there to glibly conclude, "Oh yes, I can be justified before God by doing X, Y, and Z."

Up-voted +1. Paul's own personal experience (Romans 7, all of the chapter) demonstrates that there is no such thing as a 'law-keeper' (in deed, heart and mind) on this earth. All have sinned and failed of the glory of God (and the purposes of the Father).

Answer
We should have an “integrated” understanding of “dikaiosis” if we want to live out our faith. A partial or one sided approach will derail our course.
Explanation
The Scripture is a jigsaw puzzle (Isaiah 28:13) where the several points of a single topic are scattered all over the place. Let us collect all the points and place them “line upon line” so that the “precept upon precept” will become clear.

Justified by Grace


We are “justified freely by His grace through the
redemption in Christ Jesus” (Rom 3:24).


Justified by Christ’s blood


“Much more then, being justified now by His blood,
we shall be saved from the wrath through Him” (Rom 5:9).


Justified by faith


“Then being justified by faith, we have peace with God through
our Lord Jesus Christ” (Rom 5:1).


Justified by doing Law


“For not the hearers of the Law are just with God, but the doers of
the Law shall be justified” (Rom 2:13).

If one removes one point, one does not get the whole picture.
So, we are justified by God’s grace, by Christ’s blood, by faith and by doing the spiritual Law.
The spiritual Law vs. the Works of Law
When Paul talks about the Works of Law or the Deeds of Law, people mistake it for the Law of God (Ten Commandments) which is “holy”, “just” (dikaios), “good” (Rom 7:12) and “spiritual” (Rom 7:14).
But Scripture shows that the spiritual Law of God (the Ten Commandments) is entirely different from the Works of Law:

“Because by works of Law not one of all flesh will be
justified before Him” (Rom 3:20).


“but the doers of the Law shall be justified” (Rom 2:13).

If God’s Law is the same as the Works of Law, then Romans 3:20 and Romans 2:13 are contradiction in the Scripture!
But Lord Jesus said the Scripture cannot be contradicted (John 10:35).
So, we can rest assured that the Works of Law are not spiritual but “fleshly ordinances” (Heb 9:10) and are in direct contrast to the spiritual Law of God (the Ten Commandments).
Paul’s Advice

“seek eagerly the spiritual things” (1 Cor 14:1).


“the Law is spiritual” (Rom 7:14).

So, the spiritual man of God must be a “doer of the Law” (Rom 2:13).
Conclusion
We are justified not only by faith but also by God’s grace, by Christ’s blood and by doing God’s Law.
Remove one from the above and we have no salvation!

Like the Jews before Christ’s advent (or before they have heard about His advent) should have lived according to precepts of the Law and it justified them in relative terms - for all
Law holds a relative value as preparation to the advent of Christ and the beginning of the Era of Grace and Truth - similarly, Christians are justified, but already in absolute terms by life according to Christ’s commandments through faith in His salvific grace, which faith provides His presence and action in our hearts.
Like those who only listened to the Law but did not act accordingly were not justified even in relative terms, so also those nominal Christians who only listen to precepts of Christ but remain faithless and thruough this faithlessness block Christ’s salvational working in their hearts,  are not justified in absolute terms.

Good question! Because in the bible we can also read this:
Revelation 13:9-10 (EN-TL)  If any man have an ear, let him hear.
He that leadeth into captivity shall go into captivity: he that killeth with the sword must be killed with the sword. Here is the patience and the faith of the saints.
Faith of the saints can be changed or reversed. After the beast subdue earth with his authority, the patience and the faith of the saint becomes for captivity and killings. This is evident in our times, churches teach members killings rather than love to enemies. People are taught to be captive to be a saint being submissive to the order of their respective church and pastors as saints leading this captivations. Same like the interpretation of your question, wrongly interpreted will result to our captivity but rightly divided it will be our freedom. "Dikaioo" means to show or demonstrate righteousness. How to interpret this? Let us ask our Lord:
Matthew 3:15 (EN-TL)  And Jesus answering said unto him, Suffer it to be so now: for thus it becometh us to fulfil all righteousness. Then he suffered him.
Even our Lord Jesus Crist fulfil all righteousness, that a man should be baphtized and be born again, even Him. Even if John knew that in line is a higher authority than he is, they continue to fulfil all righteousness. How is that being taught by our Lord?
Matthew 6:33 (EN-TL)  But seek ye first the kingdom of God, and his righteousness; and all these things shall be added unto you.
"Seek ye first..." as what our Lord Jesus is telling us, the first thing to seek instead of clothing, food, shelter: is the kingdom of God and His righteouness. Very Good indeed what you are searching for is it for justification or righteousness? For God doing the commanments is essential rather than knowing it. Why?
Romans 2:14-15 (EN-TL)  For when the Gentiles, which have not the law, do by nature the things contained in the law, these, having not the law, are a law unto themselves:
Which shew the work of the law written in their hearts, their conscience also bearing witness, and their thoughts the mean while accusing or else excusing one another;)
We will just contineu reading the asked verse we will find out that we humans have a born commandements or law within us. This helps us to socialize and to deal and to behave as humans. We enhance good deeds need not us know the law but the law which is writen by God in our hearts is what He wanted to manifest by us. Then, this will not be of hypocracy because it is our naturality as good men. I hope to suffice your inquiry by the teaching of our Lord Jesus which is written in the Scriptures and with the help of the Holy Spirit, Thanks be to God!
Grace of the Lord be with you all.
